# Getting pip to work in remote home directory (UNIX)

Tags: python, unix, pip

sorry for the basic question. I am very confused as to why my pip is not working on a remote unix machine. I have installed Python 3.5 in my home directory. In my PATH I have added

```
~/lib/python3.5
```

I also added to .bashrc

```
$ alias python=~/bin/python3.5
```

so when I type $ python in the command line, I get python 3.5. I can import pip from inside python (import pip) no problems. 
However using

```
$ pip install cython
```

I get: '-bash: pip: command not found'
And if I try:

```
$ python -m pip install cython
```

I get:

'Collecting cython

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cython (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cython'

Pip does not seem to be installed properly. Do I need to add anything to .bashrc?

Comment: From the [python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/), the latest stable version is  version 3.4.3. Did you look on the issues of the pre-release of python?

Comment: No, but I tried this with 3.4 and also got the same message

Comment: Try to find the actual `pip` executable in your local install. It seems not to be in *~/lib/python3.5*, directly. Also, try with `pip -v -v -v install cython` to get more information on why the search fails.

Comment: Nice. I can see a connection gets established but the SSL certificate fails: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/cython/: connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646) - skipping

Comment: I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi which may be the same problem

Comment: Make sure your clock is set correctly.